# Send array with Ajax to PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have array made by function **.push**. In array is very large data. How is the best way send this to PHP script?

```
   dataString = ??? ; // array?
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script.php",
        data: dataString, 
        cache: false,

        success: function(){
            alert("OK");
        }
    });
```

script.php:

```
  $data = $_POST['data'];

  // here i would like use foreach:

  foreach($data as $d){
     echo $d;
  }
```

How is the best way for this?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Encode your data string into JSON.

```
dataString = ??? ; // array?
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(dataString);
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script.php",
        data: {data : jsonString}, 
        cache: false,

        success: function(){
            alert("OK");
        }
    });
```

**In your PHP**

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

  // here i would like use foreach:

  foreach($data as $d){
     echo $d;
  }
```

**Note**

When you send data via POST, it needs to be as a keyvalue pair.

Thus

`data: dataString`

is wrong. Instead do:

`data: {data:dataString}`

Comment: Why use `JSON.stringify`?  What's wrong with just `data: {data: dataString}`?

Comment: @Rocket: I suppose you could do that as well in which case Jquery would serialize the array.

Comment: Then you wouldn't need `json_decode`, `$_POST['data']` would already be an array.

Comment: Friendly reminder to always validate your post values throwing them around.

Answer (score 9):

```
 dataString = [];
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script.php",
        data:{data: $(dataString).serializeArray()}, 
        cache: false,

        success: function(){
            alert("OK");
        }
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: Since `serializeArray` works by creating a JSOn string, you would first need to use `json_decode` on the PHP side

Comment: I'd suggsst dropping `serializeArray`, and just doing `data: {data: dataString}`.  Then `$_POST['data']` will be an array.

Answer (score 4):

If you have been trying to send a one dimentional array and **jquery was converting it to comma separated values >:(** then follow the code below and **an actual array will be submitted** to `php` and not all the comma separated bull**it.

Say you have to attach a single dimentional array named `myvals`.

```
jQuery('#someform').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();

    var myvals = [21, 52, 13, 24, 75]; // This array could come from anywhere you choose 
    for (i = 0; i < myvals.length; i++) {
        data.push({
            name: "myvals[]", // These blank empty brackets are imp!
            value: myvals[i]
        });
    }

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: jQuery(this).attr('action'),
    dataType: "json",
    data: data, // You have to just pass our data variable plain and simple no Rube Goldberg sh*t.
    success: function (r) {
...
```

Now inside `php` when you do this

```
print_r($_POST);
```

You will get ..

```
Array
(
    [someinputinsidetheform] => 023
    [anotherforminput] => 111
    [myvals] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
            [1] => 52
            [2] => 13
            [3] => 24
            [4] => 75
        )
)
```

Pardon my language, but there are hell lot of [Rube-Goldberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) solutions scattered all over the web and specially on SO, but none of them are elegant or solve the problem of **actually posting a one dimensional array to `php` via ajax post**. Don't forget to spread this solution.

Answer (score 3):

Data in jQuery `ajax()` function accepts anonymous objects as its input, see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). So example of what you're looking for is:

```js
dataString = {key: 'val', key2: 'val2'};
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script.php",
        data: dataString, 
        cache: false,

        success: function(){
            alert("OK");
        }
    });
```

You may also write POST/GET query on your own, like `key=val&key2=val2`, but you'd have to handle escaping yourself which is impractical.

Comment: This didn't work for me, however `data: { id_arr: [array variable goes here]}` will be accessible as array `$_POST['id_arr']` in PHP

Answer (score 1):

dataString suggests the data is formatted in a string (and maybe delimted by a character).

```
$data = explode(",", $_POST['data']);
foreach($data as $d){
     echo $d;
}
```

if dataString is not a string but infact an array (what your question indicates) use JSON.

Comment: dataString this is only example. I dont must use this, but i dont know what i must use

Comment: `data: { id_arr: [array variable goes here]},` will be accessible as `$_POST['id_arr']` as an array in PHP