# Pass array through jquery ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays

Trying to pass an array to a php page using an ajax request. The current response is `ction Array() { [native code] }` as opposed to the actual array contents (which im positive is not empty). Here my code:

```
    function GetPaginationPage(array1) {
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(array1);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/get_pagination_page.php",
        data: {data : jsonString},
        success: function(data){ 
        $('.contestants_list').append(data);
        }
        });
};
```

UPDated with json, its now passing 'undefined'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send array with Ajax to PHP script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001526/send-array-with-ajax-to-php-script)

Comment: use an Object instead, everything is preatty much the same. Like data = new Object() ... data['some_key'] = 'some_value'; ... and you can send it over just fine.

Comment: How are you calling `GetPaginationPage`?  What happens when you `console.log(array1)`?

Comment: Using a php array.`GetPaginationPage(<?php echo $contestants_array; ?>);` $contestants_array being an array

Comment: @JonahKatz: You can't pass PHP arrays to JavaScript like that.  Use `GetPaginationPage(<?php echo json_encode($contestants_array); ?>);`

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to use `JSON.stringify` here.  Just send the array normally to PHP.

```
function GetPaginationPage(array1) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "includes/get_pagination_page.php",
        data: {
            data: array1
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('.contestants_list').append(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Now in PHP, `$_POST['data']` will be an array.

UPDATE: You said you're calling `GetPaginationPage` like this:

```
GetPaginationPage(<?php echo $contestants_array; ?>);
```

You need to change that to:

```
GetPaginationPage(<?php echo json_encode($contestants_array); ?>);
```

When you `echo` an array in PHP, it gets converted to the string `"Array"`, which is intrepreted by JavaScript as the `Array` object.

Comment: think were getting close. Its now posting `data:[object Object]
data:[object Object]
data:[object Object]` where we need the actual object, not the face that its an object

Comment: @JonahKatz: Seems like it's being converted to a string somewhere.  Make sure you're not using `.join(',')`, that won't work with an array of objects.  What happens when you `console.log(array1)`?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the array to a string before passing it like so:

```
array1.join(',');
```

Or if it's a complex array consider JSON:

```
JSON.stringify(array1);
```

Comment: Update my question using your answer. its now passing underfined

Comment: Which simply means there's nothing in your variable. Are you sure you have something in "array1"?

Comment: Yes. I i can print it and theres tons of data. Is it possible im not passing it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this was to create the array in JavaScript as a delimited (~) string & then I used the explode php function to load into an array.