# Sending JSON data using ajax issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following code:

```
var arr = {City:'Moscow', Age:25};

$.ajax({
    url: "<? echo $this->createUrl('cities/index');?>",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(arr),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

The result is `null`. In the PHP side I have:

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

and

```
print_r($_POST);
```

But both are giving empty results (checked Firebug also).

Comment: Remove `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you don't need to stringyfy the data because data should be PlainObject or String but in your case you can simply write like below

```
var arr = {City:'Moscow', Age:25};

       $.ajax({
            url: "<? echo $this->createUrl('cities/index');?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: arr,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

as documented in jquery official site https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> data
>
> Type: PlainObject or String
>
> > Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
> >     not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See
> >     processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must
> >     be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple
> >     values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting
> >     (described below).

Comment: I have one more question. I replaced object to array, var arr= [1, 2, 3]; ... and  .. data: JSON.stringify(arr).. but it is not sending, I tried without stringfy also.

Comment: check this out it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890524/pass-array-to-ajax-request-in-ajax @SarvarNishonboyev http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455000/pass-array-through-jquery-ajax-request

Comment: I got it, it helped so much. great!

Answer (score 3):

You can also set the `dataType` in Ajax to specify the content type as follows.

```
       var city='city name';
       var age=10; 

       $.ajax({
            url: "<? echo $this->createUrl('cities/index');?>",
            type: "POST",
            data:"City="+city+"&Age="+age,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

and in `cities/index.php`  you can get this data by follows

```
if($_POST){

         $city=$_POST['City'];
         $age=$_POST['Age'];

         // and do with $city and $age what you want.
         //for return anything thing to `json` use follows we pass $age back to ajax
         echo json_encode($age);

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `data` option passed to `$.ajax()` must be either a simple object, that jQuery will transform into a string of the format`key1=value1&key2=value2..` OR it should be a string of the form `key1=value1&key2=value2..`.

In your case, it can be solved by passing the object itself and letting jQuery do the query string formatting:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: arr,
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var arr = {City:'Moscow', Age:25};

       $.ajax({
            url: "<? echo $this->createUrl('cities/index');?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: arr,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```