# Posting Array to PHP using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, posting

I'm having issues posting an Array to a PHP page using AJAX. I've been using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001526/send-array-with-ajax-to-php-script) as guidance, but for whatever reason I still can't get it to work. From what I can tell by using `print_r($_POST)`, I am posting an empty Array, but on the HTML/Javascript page I use an alert to see that the Array has been filled. The post is working because it inputs blank values into a MySQL database on post, but I can't figure out why it is passing an empty Array. The code is as follows:

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var routeID = "testRoute";
    var custID = "testCustID";
    var stopnumber = "teststopnumber";
    var customer = "testCustomer";
    var lat = 10;
    var lng = 20;
    var timeStamp = "00:00:00";


    var dataArray = new Array(7);
  dataArray[0]= "routeID:" + routeID;
  dataArray[1]= "custID:" + custID;
  dataArray[2]= "stopnumber:" + stopnumber;
  dataArray[3]= "customer:" + customer;
  dataArray[4]= "latitude:" + lat;
  dataArray[5]= "longitude:" + lng; 
  dataArray[6]= "timestamp:" + timeStamp; 
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
  function postData(){
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "AddtoDatabase.php", //includes full webserver url
       data: {data : jsonString}, 
       cache: false,

       success: function(){
           alert("OK");
       }
    });
  window.location = "AddtoDatabase.php"; //includes full webserver url
  }
alert(JSON.stringify(dataArray))
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  print_r($_POST);


$routeID = $_POST['routeID'];
  $custID = $_POST['custID'];
  $stopnumber = $_POST['stopnumber'];
  $customer = $_POST['customer'];
  $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
  $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
  $timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'];

$mysqli= new mysqli("fdb5.biz.nf","username","password","database");

mysqli_select_db($mysqli,"database");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Locations (routeID, custID, stopnumber, customer, latitude, longitude, timestamp) VALUES " .
           "('$routeID','$custID','$stopnumber','$customer','$latitude','$longitude','$timestamp')";
    mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql); 

    $error = mysqli_error($mysqli);  
echo $error;
?>
```

`print_r($_POST)` only displays Array() on the php page while the jsonString alert on the javascript page shows 
`["routeID:testRoute",
"custID:testCustID",
"stopnumber:teststopnumber",
"customer:testCustomer",
"latitude:10",
"longitude:20",
"timestamp:00:00:00"]`

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: instead of using jsonString use dataArray, and this array will be available in $_POST['data']

Comment: I tried that as well but it still returns Array() on the php side

Comment: Use F12 in chrome or firefox+firebug to access the Network log and see what really got sent through. You should verify that a POST request was done, and what its parameters (POST DATA) were.

Comment: @Lewyx It does not look as if a POST request was even made. It seems to just be ignoring the AJAX and continuing on with window.relocation

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Note:** The *main* cause for your code to output `array()` is the fact that you're redirecting the client *before the asynchronous (AJAX) request has been sent/processed* 
Basically move `window.location = "AddtoDatabase.php";` to the success callback, as mentioned further down.

First problem: Instead of using an array, you should use an object literal (~= assoc array in php).

To do so, change this bit:

```
var dataArray = new Array(7);//<== NEVER do this again, btw
dataArray[0]= "routeID:" + routeID;
dataArray[1]= "custID:" + custID;
dataArray[2]= "stopnumber:" + stopnumber;
dataArray[3]= "customer:" + customer;
dataArray[4]= "latitude:" + lat;
dataArray[5]= "longitude:" + lng; 
dataArray[6]= "timestamp:" + timeStamp;
```

And write this, instead:

```
var dataObject = { routeID: routeID,
                   custID:  custID,
                   stopnumber: stopnumber
                   customer: customer,
                   latitude: lat,
                   longitute: lng,
                   timestamp: timeStamp};
```

There's nothing more too it. To finish off, just send the data like so:

```
function postData()
{
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
             url: "AddtoDatabase.php",
             data: dataObject,//no need to call JSON.stringify etc... jQ does this for you
             cache: false,
             success: function(resopnse)
             {//check response: it's always good to check server output when developing...
                 console.log(response);
                 alert('You will redirect in 10 seconds');
                 setTimeout(function()
                 {//just added timeout to give you some time to check console
                    window.location = 'AddtoDatabase.php';
                 },10000);
             }
    });
```

Secondly, your `postData` function redirects the client before the AJAX request has been sent! After the call to `$.ajax`, you have a `window.location = "AddtoDatabase.php";` statement in your code. If you want the client to be redirected after the ajax call, you will have to move that expression to your `success` callback function (the one where I log the `response`) in the second snippet ^^.

When you've changed all this, your `$_POST` variable should look about right. If not, print out the `$_REQUEST` object and see what the response of an ajax call is then.

Lastly, *please* be aware that using an api that supports prepared statements (and thus protects you against **most** injection attacks), that doesn't mean stringing unchecked POST/GET data into a query is any safer than it used to be...
Bottom line: When you use an API that supports critical safety features such as prepared statements *use those features*.

Just to be absolutely clear, and complete, here's a slightly reworked version of the PHP code, too:

```
$routeID = $_POST['routeID'];
$custID = $_POST['custID'];
$stopnumber = $_POST['stopnumber'];
$customer = $_POST['customer'];
$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
$timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'];
//you're connecting OO-style, why do you switch to procedural next?
//choose one, don't mix them, that makes for fugly code:
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('fdb5.biz.nf', 'username', 'password', 'database');//procedural
//or, more in tune with the times:
$mysqli= new mysqli("fdb5.biz.nf","username","password","database");//OO

mysqli_select_db($mysqli,"database");
//or
$mysqli->select_db('database');
```

Check the docs to see the procedural counterpart of all methods I'll be using from here on end, if you want. I prefer the OOP-API

```
//making a prepared statement:
$query = 'INSERT INTO Locations 
          (routeID, custID, stopnumber, customer, latitude, longitude, timestamp) VALUES 
          (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)))
{
    echo $query.' failed to prepare';
    exit();
}
$stmt->bind_param('s', $routeID);
$stmt->bind_param('s',$custID);
//and so on
$stmt->bind_param('d', $latitude);//will probably be a double
$stmt->execute();//query DB
```

Useful links on prepared statements:

- [`mysqli::prepare` doc page](http://www.php.net/mysqli_prepare)
- [`mysqli_stmt::bind_result` doc page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) is invaluable when it comes to fetching data...
- [quick tutorial 1](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3599166/Connecting-and-prepared-statements-with-the-mysqli-extension.htm)
- [Q&A-styled tutorial 2](http://www.phpmysqlitutorials.com/)
- Just in case: a [`PDO` tutorial, too](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: I thought I'd changed everything to mysqli. Where do you still see mysql_?

Comment: @EvanEzell: Sorry, I just noticed you _are_ using `mysqli_*`, however: you're using it badly (very insecure)

Comment: @EvanEzell: Edited bit about `mysql_*` being deprecated, to reflect on the security holes in your PHP code

Comment: I'll look into that thank you. Although the input is going to be very tightly managed.

Comment: I don't mind down-votes, unless there is no explanation for them: so please explain the -1, did I miss anything 2.5 years ago?

Comment: (I didnt downvote) The binding didn't work for me, I had to do everything in 1 bind eg `$stmt->bind_param('ss...', $routeID , $custID... );`

Answer (score 0):

you should use serialize. then......

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#submit").click( function(event) {

/* stop form from submitting normally */
 event.preventDefault();

 /*clear result div*/
 $("#loginresponse").html('');

 /* use serialize take everthing into array */
    var frmdata = $("#formname").serialize();

$.ajax({
  url: "/file.php",
  type: "post",
  dataType: "json",
  data: frmdata,
  success: function(data, textStatus){
    if(data.redirect == 'true'){
       $('#formresponse').html(data.message);
      return true;
    }else{
      $('#formresponse').html(data.message);
      return false;
    }
  },
  error:function(){
      $("#formresponse").html('error');
  }
});
});
}); 

</script>
```

than in php take data with post

```
<?php
$routeID = $_POST['routeID'];
$custID = $_POST['custID'];
$stopnumber = $_POST['stopnumber'];
$customer = $_POST['customer'];
$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
$timestamp = $_POST['timestamp'];
?>
```

and display with json encode. this way you can display errors

```
<?php 

if(true)
    echo json_encode(array('redirect'=>'true', 'message'=>'form submitted'));
else
    echo json_encode(array('redirect'=>'false', 'message'=>'form not submited'));
?>
```

Comment: jQuery automatically serializes data... that's not the issue: the issue is both the `window.location` statement (OP overlooked async nature of AJAX) and left his app wide open to injection

Comment: Okay misunderstanding... you are right. but I hope my answer helps someone else too!

Comment: This might come across as being _blunt & arrogant_ but it won't. Your answer can't help anybody, because all you're doing is manually serializing the data. If you leave that bit out, jQ will serialize it _for you_, so you're writing the same code twice. Look at how I pass the data to the `$.ajax` method: it's just a simple object literal. jQuery will serialize it for me, and send it correctly, without my having to think about any of that.

Comment: Also: `preventDefault` on `$('#submit').click` doesn't cut it: <enter> doesn't trigger `click`, but does submit the form. Use `$('#frm').submit(function(){});`, or better yet: `delegate`, and both `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` should be invoked. The quickes way in jQuery to do this is simply to `return false` from the callback