# pass javascript variable to another php page

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am working on google maps api where i have to calculate the distance from current location to user selected destination.
The list of destinations are stored in javascript array as:

```
var details = [
    {
        'title': 'Sobo Central Mall',
        'address': 'PTMM Malvia Marg,Tardeo Road,Mumbai.',
        'lat': '18.975684',
        'lng': '72.811910',
        'open': 'NA',
        'close': 'NA',
        'sex': 'Unisex',
        'place': 'mall'
    }
    //and so on...
];
```

which I display in list:

```
for (i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
    var place= details[i].title;
    var add= details[i].address;
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML +='<p>'+ place+ '<br><div id="address"> ' + add +'</div></p><br/><hr/>';
```

here i want to call the another php `i.e.direction.php` file to which i can pass `add` variable

```
<a href="direction.php?add="+add+">dir</a>
```

And in direction.php:

```
<?php $add = $_GET['add'];?>
<script>
document.getElementById('desti').innerHTML = "<?php echo $add ?>";
</script>
```

But `$add` doesn't have any value in it.
Can anyone sort out the error?or suggest any different way to pass the js variable to another php file.

Comment: Where do you render that link? I only see code that displays the address.

Comment: inspect element <a> in browser first

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041835/posting-array-to-php-using-ajax

Comment: add a hidden variable on page and assign the value of add to it using javascript. On click of link call a javascript function which will redirect to desired page appending the value.  like window.location.href='directions.php?add='+document.getElementById("<id of hidden element>").value()

Comment: One more thing to remember is that the address might have characters that might break the query string, so use [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) to escape the address.

Comment: @user1844933 i inspect the <a> tag it is showing `<a +add+"="" href="direction.php?add=">dir</a>` that means it is null do u know how can i overcome this?

Comment: @DeepakVishwakarma plz explain in more detail

Comment: It seems you will be having multiple add variables , right?  Can u share the link for html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add in  tag was getting null value
Quotes problem:

`<a href="direction.php?add='+add+'">dir</a>//single quotes for add`

Answer (score 0):

add variable can't be call like this in html

So you have to use javascript to replace the url.

Give id to your anchor tag like this

```
<a id="myAnchor" href="direction.php?add=default_value">dir</a>
```

At the end when value is inserted in variable add then you write this

```
document.getElementById("myAnchor").href = "direction.php?add="+add;
```

Hope this will help

Comment: my anchor tag is inside the for loop so it directly takes the value i guess

Comment: can you provide that line of code. It will be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

In html you should give a class instance name to a div (example: ajaxPostHandler)
then in your javascript assign a click event to that div and fire a ajax post event (example: doAjaxPost())

```
$(".ajaxPostHandler).click(function(){
  doAjaxPost();
})  

function doAjaxPost(){
     $.post('direction.php',{
           add: add

        },function(response){
            if(response.success){
            }
            else{
            }
        });
   }
```

HTML

```
<div class="ajaxPostHandler">dir</div>
```

Comment: i don't have knowledge about ajax can u tell me how can i call ajax in anchor tag. or ajax will work on click?