# How to access Javascript array in PHP file and printing array values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I have first PHP file where I have form and it's action is directing me to next php file. The code snippet is as below:

```
 <form name="drugForm" action="drug_form2.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
```

In function validateForm (javascript) I am checking whether text area is filled and at least a checkbox is checked. And I am creating array, here in javascript, to get checkbox values. The js code is below:

```
 function validateForm()
 {
   var x=document.forms["drugForm"]["dname"].value;
   var y=document.drugForm.drug;
   var y_array = [];

    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
 alert("First name must be filled out");
 return false;
    }

    else if (Boolean(x))
    {
 for(k=0;k<y.length;k++)
 {
    if(y[k].checked)
    {
        var arr_val = y[k].value;
        y_array.push(arr_val);
        //alert(arr_val);
    }

 }

for(m=0;m<y.length;m++)
{
    if(y[m].checked)
    {
        for(l=0;l<y_array.length;l++)
        {
            alert("This is array " + y_array[l]);
        }

        dataString = y_array ; // array?
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(dataString);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "drug_form2.php",
            data: {data : jsonString}, 
            cache: false,

            success: function(){
                alert("OK");
        }
        });

        //alert("The array length is " + y_array.length);
        //return true;
    }
   }

   alert("Check one checkbox at least");
   return false;
   }
  }
```

Here, from this function I want send array to php, for this reason I referred following link but it didn't work:

[Send array with Ajax to PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001526/send-array-with-ajax-to-php-script)

Now, my queries are as following:

Why am I not able to print array value inside second for loop? and
How can I access javascript array in PHP file?

I have PHP file too to check whether array values are printing properly, but it is not giving those values. Below is second PHP file to get javascript array in PHP file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
  </head>
   <body>
  <?php
   $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

 // here i would like use foreach:

  foreach($data as $d){
   echo $d;
   }
    echo "Its in form2 and working fine";
   ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Am I including ajax function at right place?

Answer (score 0):

You can just append each item in your javascript array into a string seperated by a unique character/s. As for my experience, it's easier than passing it as an array. Then pass the string to PHP.

In your PHP code, use the string method `explode` to create an array out of the string. Then go with the rest of your code logic.

Answer (score 0):

if javascript array is simple array,than change it to csv and passed it has string.

In php serverside just explode that string you will again get array in php.

**javscript**

```
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "drug_form2.php",
                 data: {data : y_array.join(',')}, 
                 cache: false,
                 success: function(){
                     alert("OK");
                }
             });
```

**php**

```
        $array= explode(",", $_POST['data']);
```

Comment: Actually I had used same one, modified one, but it didn't work. Am I correct in placing ajax function in javascript?

Comment: your ajax function should be outside for loop