# How to send JavaScript array using AJAX to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to send a JavaScript array to the server when a user clicks on a button.

My current code is as follows, but it does not work, could someone help me with this?

HTML

```
<?
    $arrs = {include for database}
    $js_array = json_encode($arrs);
?>
<script>
    var dataArray = <?php echo $js_array; ?>;
    var jsData = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "savepos.php",
        datatype: "JSON",
        data: {data : jsData},
        success: function() {
            alert('success!');
        }
    });
</script>
```

**savepos.php**

```
$data_array = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
```

However, I get `$data_array` as null ?

Comment: Why do you use `stripslashes()` here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send array with Ajax to PHP script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001526/send-array-with-ajax-to-php-script)

Comment: No `stripslashes` required here, and you should maybe put quotes around your `<?php echo $js_array; ?>` line

Comment: I use json_decode($_POST['data']); It's not work. I dont't know.

Comment: What's the value of `$_POST['data']`? Do you get an `alert('success!');` when you run this? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: The dataType attribute for jQuery specifies how to handle the responding data, not the sending data. The sent data is always converted into a URL encoded string. If you don't use JSON.stringify() you can use $_POST['data'] directly. Then json_encode on the PHP side.

Answer (score 3):

You can just send the array without using JSON.stringify(). There is no need for it, as you set the datatype. Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fFfsD/)

Open up chromes network tools before you hit run to see the form data being sent. Then you can use

```
<?php json_decode($_POST['data']); ?>
```