# Javascript (AJAX) send array to PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I'm trying to send an array from Javascript to PHP.

```
function wishlist_save(arr){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "from.php?type=customers",
        data: {info: JSON.stringify(arr) },
        success: function(){

        }
    }); 
}
```

The array is set this way:

```
function getAll(){
    var info = [];
    var i = 0;
    $(".desc").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        var qtt = $(this).attr('alt');

        info[i] = [];
        info[i]['desc'] = value;
        info[i]['qtt'] = qtt;

        i++;
    });

    return info;
}
```

If I output (with `console.log(getAll())`) the array in javascript I get the right values in Chrome Console:

```
[Array[0], Array[0], Array[0]]
 ->0: Array[0]
      desc: 'John'
      alt: 'Good'
 ->1: Array[0]
      desc: 'Obama'
      alt: 'Great'
```

But in PHP (`from.php?type=customers`) I can't figure out how to get those values..

```
$arr = json_decode($_POST['info']);
ChromePhp::log($arr[0]['desc']); // returns null
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Solved**.

The problem was on `JSON.stringify(arr)`, which in some way didn't send properly the array to PHP.

So, all I needed was to adapt the function that retrieves the array:

```
var info = [];
info.push({desc: value, qtt: qtt });
```

Besides that, the AJAX only now need:

```
data: {info: arr },
```

And PHP:

Comment: `print_r($arr);` what is the output of this?

Comment: try sending it as JSON, as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9001573/586051

Comment: Try `json_decode($_POST['info'], true)`, or `$arr[0]->desc`.

Comment: Check out $_POST['info'] 

that variable should contain your json encoded array.

Comment: @AwladLiton `ChromePhp::log(print_r($arr));` I receive 'True' in console.
@RahulDesai I didn't get your answer..I'm using JSON..
@DaveChen didn't work..retrieves null
@PhilipG `ChromePhp::log($_POST['info']);` retrieves `[[],[],[]]` in console.