# How to get array back in php from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have an array like this in php :

```
Array
(
    [week] => 15
    [showing] => present
    [ignore_team_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 362
            [1] => 343
            [2] => 352
            [3] => 331
        )

    [event_pasted_team_id] => Array
        (
        )

    [old_data] => old_data
)
```

I want to get this array back in php from ajax.
This is what I did so far.

I just encode the array into json and saved it in hidden field using `json_encode();`

```
<input id='myArray' type='hidden' name="myArray" value='<?php echo json_encode($myArray);?>' />
```

In javascript:

```
function ajaxloadPlage(outputId,dataTransfer){
            myArrayVal = jQuery('#myArray').val();
            strify = JSON.stringify(myArrayVal);
            jQuery.get( myapp.ajaxurl+'?'+dataTransfer,{action:'getPlayerRaterData','getArr':strify}, function( data ) {
            //business login goes here
                });
    }
```

Back in PHP:

```
if($_GET['getArr']){
    $getArr = $_GET['getArr'];
    echo '<pre>';print_r($getArr);
}
```

Its print like this:

```
\"{\\\"week\\\":15,\\\"showing\\\":\\\"present\\\",\\\"ignore_team_id\\\":[362,343,352,331],\\\"event_pasted_team_id\\\":[],\\\"old_data\\\":\\\"old_data\\\"}\"
```

How can I get the valid array back?

Comment: `echo json_encode($getArr);` ?

Comment: does this stackoverflow article help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001526/send-array-with-ajax-to-php-script

Answer (score 0):

You have encoded the array in json during sending but not decoded in back php.
try like this..

PHP:

```
<?php
if($_GET['getArr']){
    $getArr = $_GET['getArr'];
    echo '<pre>';print_r(json_decode($getArr));
}
?>
```

Hope this will solve ur issue.

Comment: I have already told that Its working for me.check my above comment.

Answer (score 0):

`myArrayVal` is already a JSON string, you don't need to call `JSON.stringify`. You should call `JSON.parse()` to convert it to an object. `$.get()` will then URL-encode the object, and PHP will decode this when it sets `$_GET['getArr']`.

```
function ajaxloadPlage(outputId,dataTransfer){
    myArrayVal = jQuery('#myArray').val();
    myArray = JSON.parse(myArrayVal);
    jQuery.get( myapp.ajaxurl+'?'+dataTransfer,{action:'getPlayerRaterData','getArr':myArray}, function( data ) {
        //business login goes here
    });
}
```