# Jquery array cannot access in php script Error: Undefined Index

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am sending a javascript array by using jquery to a php script. 
In ajax I have a myarr variable but this variable can't be accessed in php. 
Error is :

> Undefined index myarr

Please Please help me. this is really important.

This is my jquery code:

```
for (var n = 0; n < arraySubId.length; n++) {
     var ansArr = [];
     for (var m = 1; m <= 11; m++) {
         ansArr[m - 1] = $('#' + arraySubId[n] + '-' + m + '').val();
     }

     * $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         data: ({
             'sub_id': arraySubId[n],
             'myarr': ansArr
         }),
         url: 'Scripts/insert_feedback.php',
         success: function(data) {
             if (data == "1") {

             } else {
                 alert(data);
             }
         }
     }); *
 }
```

When I access myarr variable in php, it's displaying:

> Undefined index myarr.

Please Please help me.

And this is my php code:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $prn = $_SESSION['username'];

    $sub_id = $_POST['sub_id'];

    $ans_arr = $_REQUEST['myarr'];

    include 'dbclass.php';

    $dbclass = new DBClass;

    $mysqli = $dbclass->connect();

    $query = "INSERT INTO ".$sub_id."(student_prn, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, date) values('$prn', '$ans_arr[0]','$ans_arr[1]','$ans_arr[2]',
                                            '$ans_arr[3]','$ans_arr[4]','$ans_arr[5]','$ans_arr[6]',
                                            '$ans_arr[7]','$ans_arr[8]','$ans_arr[9]','$ans_arr[10]', now())";

   $msg = $dbclass->insert($query);

   echo $msg;

?>
```

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001526/send-array-with-ajax-to-php-script

Comment: You have to serialize arrays and objects before you can send them via ajax

Comment: how i can do this Please tell me, And it was working perfectly by this way, Please Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your array to Json String and send it in JS, and in PHP decode it using json_decode()

Comment: Sorry but this is not possible in this case because lot of data going to be generated dynamically Sorry

Comment: Why you use  $_POST['']; for "sub_id" data, and  $_REQUEST for "myarr" ?

Comment: Yes I treid $_POST[""] both of them BUT not working..  :(