# how to pass array in ajax call using php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 131

    [1] => 103

    [2] => 21

    [3] => 94

    [4] => 107

    [5] => 130

    [6] => 92

    [7] => 128

    [8] => 115

    [9] => 81
)
```

How to pass this array in ajax call

Javascript Code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var recentchatfriendids = []; 
//actual array
 $.ajax({ 
    url: '/friends/message/getmessagestatus';
    data: {
        recentchatfriendids : recentchatfriendids
    },
    success: function(response){
    },
  }); 
});
```

Comment: What did you tried ???

Comment: show your full javascript code

Comment: Possibly duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001526/send-array-with-ajax-to-php-script

Comment: `echo json_encode(yourArrayVariableGoesHere)`

Comment: @MayaShah that is a definite duplicate

Comment: With @RoryMcCrossan solution, on ajax side, don't forget to parse it with `JSON.parse(response)`

Comment: @MayaShah I think the OP is asking the opposite to that, ie. How do I return the above PHP array to JS?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i think OP is moving from client side to server side. SO he probably would need js code

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan way is same pass array data in Ajax.

Comment: But if you already have the array in PHP, then whats the point of making an AJAX request? That makes no sense.

Comment: please do not post your code in the comments section. Update your question

Comment: Hi Rory McCrossan i have an array based on that ids we can get all the messages information

Comment: how do you get the array? do you do this via a html form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert it into json and try it.
hope that works for you.

Comment: this should be a comment as OP has provided little information on the issue at hand

Comment: @PhpDev Thanks for your information. I answered based on what I understand,

Comment: The point is this isn't an answer. If you *show* the OP *how* to convert it to JSON then it may be.

Comment: As the question is not specifying the nature of the array whether it is in PHP or Javascript, I answered in a generalised way that user can understand what exactly to do with the array. Hoping that the user knows how to convert it into JSON in PHP and JS both.

Answer (score 0):

```
die(json_encode($arr));
```

`json_encode` converts PHP array to JSON object. die() method sends the response back to client and terminates the PHP script

Comment: @phpdev do you know what exactly Nikunj trying to do with die(). Please carefully read before you comment.

Comment: @Akin...yes.any issue with this usage?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can:

1. Convert the php array into a JSON string, using json_encode function, eg

   `$array_variable = array([0] => 131....);
   echo json_encode($array_variable,true);`
2. Then use `$.ajax({...`  to receive the echoed string and manipulate it.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score -1):

```html
In Php :
----------------
$array = array(131,103,21,94,107,130,92,128,115,81);

echo json_encode($array,1);

In JqueryCode : 
----------------------
$.ajax({
  url:'http://yourUrl.com/service', // Your Service Url
  data:{data1:data1,data2:data2}  // If You want to send data form ajax call
  type:"POST" // POST OR GET You Want
  dataType : "json" // It is important for when you pass json data to ajax
  success : function(response){
     // You Can Get Json Response
  }    

});
```