# Unable to get the JSON POST in php

Tags: php, json, ajax, post

I don't know, if this is a duplicate question to any post. As I am not able to get the exact answer of my question..

I have a Ajax request, which is sending 'Category' to a php page on a **'api.mysite.com/create.php'**

Ajax code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: _apiUrl+"create.php",
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify({ Category: Category}),
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){
    $("#myDiv").html(data);         
}});
```

And my PHP Code is like this:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
include("includes/db_connection.php");
$Category = json_decode($_POST['Category'], true);
$Category = $Category[0]['Category'];?>
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank You in advance.
Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
data: JSON.stringify({ Category: Category}),
```

To

```
data: {Category : JSON.stringify({ Category: Category})},
```

You may get solution here [Send array with Ajax to PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001526/send-array-with-ajax-to-php-script)

Comment: Hello,, Thanks for your response, but the suggested change is not working :(

Comment: Ok I found solution for you. try, accepted answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001526/send-array-with-ajax-to-php-script

Comment: **No Luck** :( :(