# Cannot send array to php via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Well I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001526/send-array-with-ajax-to-php-script) question, but cannot send array to php it returns me always empty:

JS:

```
            values = [];
            values['mpsRegnomer'] = $('#mpsRegnomer').val();
            values['mpsMarka'] = $('#mpsMarka').val();
            values['mpsMarkaOther'] = $('#mpsMarkaOther').val();
            values['engineType'] = $('#engineType').val();
            values['seatNumberInput'] = $('#seatNumberInput').val();
            values['carColor'] = $('#carColor').val();
            values['mpsChassiNum'] = $('#mpsChassiNum').val();
            values['mpsModel'] = $('#mpsModel').val();
            values['mpsModelOther'] = $('#mpsModelOther').val();
            values['mpsManufactureDate'] = $('#mpsManufactureDate').val();
            values['mpsfor'] = $('#mpsfor').val();
            values['VehicleType'] = $('#VehicleType').val();
            values['dvigatelInput'] = $('#dvigatelInput').val();
            values['engineMaxPower'] = $('#engineMaxPower').val();
            values['is_automatic'] = $('#is_automatic').val();
            console.log(values);

            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'assets/clients/services/saveDataMPS.php',
                    async: false,
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    data: {"values": JSON.stringify(values)},
                    success:function(response){
                        alert(1);
                    }
            });
```

`console.log(values)` show me that array is OK.

PHP code:

```
<?php

var_dump(json_decode($_POST["values"])); exit;
```

It returns me always empty, also tried only with `var_dump($_POST);` same result.. Where am I wrong?

Result from `console.log(values)`:

[image]

Comment: You don't need to `JSON.stringify(values)` instead, `data: { values: values }`

Comment: can you add JSON.stringify value into the question

Comment: @Cid with `data: {"values": values}` and `data: {values: values}` and `var_dump($_POST)` still empty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined `values` as an array and therefore when you stringify it, you get an empty array. Define it as an object like `values = {};` and it will work.

You don't use associative arrays in javascript because

> If you use named indexes, JavaScript will redefine the array to a
>   standard object. After that, some array methods and properties will
>   produce incorrect results.

Thats's why you need to define it as object in the beginning.

```
values = {};
values['mpsRegnomer'] = $('#mpsRegnomer').val();
values['mpsMarka'] = $('#mpsMarka').val();
values['mpsMarkaOther'] = $('#mpsMarkaOther').val();
```

Here is a working JSFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/pk97fe0b/

Comment: You are right it works with object, but how do I make ti to work with array ?

Comment: Why do you need it to be an array and not an object? Associative arrays in javascript are objects and you use objects for that purpose. `If you use named indexes, JavaScript will redefine the array to a standard object.
After that, some array methods and properties will produce incorrect results.`

Comment: I don't need it, i'm just curious :)